# How to use display: block on RWD

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've following design on the desktop [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k4rJ.jpg)

I want display those divs in display: block when resolution is mobile but it doesn't not work.

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  background-image: url("../ta3.jpg");
  background-size: 70%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top right;
}

.header .header__center {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.header .header__center .header__bussword-row {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 150px;
}

.header .header__center .header__bussword-row .bussword {
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #353535;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.header .header__center .skins-row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  top: 264px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 320px;
}

.header .header__center .skins-row .ref-wrap {
  width: 130px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #27d0d3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header .header__center .skins-row .ref-wrap:hover>.reflink-logo {
  transform: scale(120%);
  transition: .4s;
}

.header .header__center .skins-row .ref-wrap:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .7;
}

.header .header__center .skins-row .ref-wrap .reflink-logo {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -30px;
  position: absolute;
}

.header .header__center .skins-row .ref-wrap .reflink-info {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.header .header__center .skins-row .ref-wrap .reflink-info .reflink__link a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #252525;
}

.header .header__center .skins-row .ref-wrap .reflink-info .reflink__code {
  padding-top: 7px;
}

.header .header__center .skins-row .ref-wrap .reflink-info .reflink__price {
  padding-top: 7px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url("../ta3.jpg");
    background-size: 140%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
  }
  .header .header__center .skins-row {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="body light-theme">
  <section class="header col01">
    <div class="header__center">
      <div class="header__bussword-row">
        <h1 class="bussword">Dostępne reflinki</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="skins-row row02">
        <div class="ref-wrap wrap01">
          <img src="CrQS7tw.png" class="reflink-logo">
          <div class="reflink-info col-003">
            <p class="reflink__link">
              <a href="">g4skins.com</a>
            </p>
            <h5 class="reflink__code">Kod: xgleba</h5>
            <p class="reflink__price">Free 0.5$</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="skins-row row02">
        <div class="ref-wrap wrap01">
          <img src="CrQS7tw.png" class="reflink-logo">
          <div class="reflink-info col-003">
            <p class="reflink__link">
              <a href="">g4skins.com</a>
            </p>
            <h5 class="reflink__code">Kod: xgleba</h5>
            <p class="reflink__price">Free 0.5$</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="skins-row row02">
        <div class="ref-wrap wrap01">
          <img src="CrQS7tw.png" class="reflink-logo">
          <div class="reflink-info col-003">
            <p class="reflink__link">
              <a href="">g4skins.com</a>
            </p>
            <h5 class="reflink__code">Kod: xgleba</h5>
            <p class="reflink__price">Free 0.5$</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="skins-row row02">
        <div class="ref-wrap wrap01">
          <img src="CrQS7tw.png" class="reflink-logo">
          <div class="reflink-info col-003">
            <p class="reflink__link">
              <a href="">g4skins.com</a>
            </p>
            <h5 class="reflink__code">Kod: xgleba</h5>
            <p class="reflink__price">Free 0.5$</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="skins-row row02">
        <div class="ref-wrap wrap01">
          <img src="CrQS7tw.png" class="reflink-logo">
          <div class="reflink-info col-003">
            <p class="reflink__link">
              <a href="">g4skins.com</a>
            </p>
            <h5 class="reflink__code">Kod: xgleba</h5>
            <p class="reflink__price">Free 0.5$</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I tried add **display: block** to the **skins-row** class but it still does not work.

Comment: can you share an example of how it should look like in mobile?

Answer (score 0):

There is some styling I do not get and unnecessary high specificity for the selectors, but I guess your question is about stacking the `.skins-row`-elements on narrow viewports, right? You would also have to change the display property of the parent (`.header .header__center`) to see the effect, because it is set to use flex-box.

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  background-image: url("../ta3.jpg");
  background-size: 70%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top right;
}

.header .header__center {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.header .header__center .header__bussword-row {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 150px;
}

.header .header__center .header__bussword-row .bussword {
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #353535;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.header .header__center .skins-row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  top: 264px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 320px;
}

.header .header__center .skins-row .ref-wrap {
  width: 130px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #27d0d3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header .header__center .skins-row .ref-wrap:hover>.reflink-logo {
  transform: scale(120%);
  transition: .4s;
}

.header .header__center .skins-row .ref-wrap:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .7;
}

.header .header__center .skins-row .ref-wrap .reflink-logo {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -30px;
  position: absolute;
}

.header .header__center .skins-row .ref-wrap .reflink-info {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.header .header__center .skins-row .ref-wrap .reflink-info .reflink__link a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #252525;
}

.header .header__center .skins-row .ref-wrap .reflink-info .reflink__code {
  padding-top: 7px;
}

.header .header__center .skins-row .ref-wrap .reflink-info .reflink__price {
  padding-top: 7px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url("../ta3.jpg");
    background-size: 140%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
  }
  .header .header__center .skins-row {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}

/* added */

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .header .header__center {
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  }
  .header .header__center .skins-row {
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="body light-theme">
  <section class="header col01">
    <div class="header__center">
      <div class="header__bussword-row">
        <h1 class="bussword">Dostępne reflinki</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="skins-row row02">
        <div class="ref-wrap wrap01">
          <img src="CrQS7tw.png" class="reflink-logo">
          <div class="reflink-info col-003">
            <p class="reflink__link">
              <a href="">g4skins.com</a>
            </p>
            <h5 class="reflink__code">Kod: xgleba</h5>
            <p class="reflink__price">Free 0.5$</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="skins-row row02">
        <div class="ref-wrap wrap01">
          <img src="CrQS7tw.png" class="reflink-logo">
          <div class="reflink-info col-003">
            <p class="reflink__link">
              <a href="">g4skins.com</a>
            </p>
            <h5 class="reflink__code">Kod: xgleba</h5>
            <p class="reflink__price">Free 0.5$</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="skins-row row02">
        <div class="ref-wrap wrap01">
          <img src="CrQS7tw.png" class="reflink-logo">
          <div class="reflink-info col-003">
            <p class="reflink__link">
              <a href="">g4skins.com</a>
            </p>
            <h5 class="reflink__code">Kod: xgleba</h5>
            <p class="reflink__price">Free 0.5$</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="skins-row row02">
        <div class="ref-wrap wrap01">
          <img src="CrQS7tw.png" class="reflink-logo">
          <div class="reflink-info col-003">
            <p class="reflink__link">
              <a href="">g4skins.com</a>
            </p>
            <h5 class="reflink__code">Kod: xgleba</h5>
            <p class="reflink__price">Free 0.5$</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="skins-row row02">
        <div class="ref-wrap wrap01">
          <img src="CrQS7tw.png" class="reflink-logo">
          <div class="reflink-info col-003">
            <p class="reflink__link">
              <a href="">g4skins.com</a>
            </p>
            <h5 class="reflink__code">Kod: xgleba</h5>
            <p class="reflink__price">Free 0.5$</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```